# How to display Bing Map in Callout Popup as it display in SharePoint 2013 for GeoLocation Field?

Tags: 2013, app

I have to display Bing Map in Callout Popup as displayed in SharePoint 2013 Geo Location Field.

NOTE : I have to use Out of the box Geo Location Field and take value from that field.
I am using it in App Part.

I want to Display as shown in this  [LINK](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/geo-location-field-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Tobias Zimmergren's blogpost about that specific matter? [Here](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-getting-started-with-the-new-geolocation-field-in-sharepoint-2013) he shows how to use the field and how to do some nice stuff with it. What you want to do is basically OOTB functionality all the way as I understand it.

You just need to add the geofield to the list for example with powershell like this (cred. Zimmergren):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$web = Get-SPWeb "http://tozit-sp:2015"
$list = $web.Lists["Scandinavian Microsoft Offices"]
$list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
    "<Field Type='Geolocation' DisplayName='Office Location'/>",
    $true,
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
```

Comment: Thanks Robert,
I have already added Geo Location field to my List but my requirement is something different. I have added a callout popup in my AppPart and I want to display Bing map in that callout popup.